# How can I use SQL database with Entity Framework to convert string values locally

Tags: sql, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

I'm using MS entity framework in an asp.net webforms website. I have a table that will likely be edited infrequently, but editing is important. When an edit is pending (not yet approved), I use a "pending" edit table to store the id, column name, and a string version of the value (which could be anything) in this pending table, then when it's accepted I need to load the pending item and apply that change to the original table. entities is strongly typed so I need a way of on the fly converting the values from a string to "whatever" type that column is. using pure SQL you can make an update statement and the server will try to convert the string (because sql is always a string) into that column type, but is there a way to do it with entity framework?

I've hacked around and found how to get to the properties that match the column name from a string, but I can't see a clear way (other than hard coding a look up table object that will try to parse each type based on what I hard code the types to be) Is there a better way?

Comment: I created an extension method that uses `Convert.ChangeType` to to convert strings to whatever objects I need on the fly, using `Nullable.GetUnderlyingType()` and checking if that types is `IConvertible`. This worked for most types, I just had to write a condition for each type that I used that wasn't `IConverible`. It all felt very hacky, but it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It can get little messy but you could create a structure/class with the tableids and related update field type. Then you could use the tableid to get the type and do a parse on that type with the string value on hand.

Another approach i could advice is not using a separate table. Make a copy of the edited table row, put a edit_pending column flag, and an original_row_id column. Later when edit approved just update the original_row_id and delete the copied row.

Comment: I agree with you on the suggested approach of copying the edited row.

Comment: duplicating row is a bad idea in this case because there are 50+ columns and they will always be edited one at a time, I also have to know which column is the one that changed to show only that change for the approval system.

I know I can create a class that does all the conversions, but there should be a cleaner solution, since database drivers already do this, I just don't know how to access it.

Comment: You can create a  string property with getter and setter MyStringValue. On set you can cast the string to the correct type with parse and set the real property and update.

Comment: That does sound like a good solution, but can I edit the entity framework autogen classes and lock them so they don't change if I have update them from the database?

Comment: You mean not modifying EF classes and manually changing database design? It is possible. Normally the approach in EF is Code First. Where you create the model and EF creates related tables in database. You could also use Database First, where you manually create your database and code related model objects yourself.